# How to use InputProps of TextField in <input /> element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to use the `InputProps` in `<input />` element instead of `<TextField />` of Material UI?

My Input.js component where I have used `InputProps`:

```
const Input = ({name, handleChange, type, handleShowPassword}) => {

    return(
        
        <input 
            name={name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            require
            type={type}
            InputProps={name === 'password' && {
                endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <IconButton onClick={handleShowPassword}>
                            {type === 'password' ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                ),
            }}
        />
    )
}

export default Input
```

SignUp.js:

```
const SignUp = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Input name="firstName" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input name="password" type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'} handleShowPassword={handleShowPassword} />                              
        </div>
    )
}
export default SignUp
```

Please any help would be appreciated or feel free to share if there are any other ways to achieve the result.

Comment: the `input` element is an HTML element, whereas `<TextField />` is from Material UI. You'd have to create a custom Input component where you map the input prop attributes into the `<input .../>` element.

Comment: @Mohaimin I know InputProps is a material UI thing. Isn't there any other way without making a component? Like an attribute where I can fit in.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You could use `import { Input } from '@mui/material';` and apply `inputProps` over it. MUI Doc Link - https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/#demos

Answer (score -3):

My suggestion is you need to use Tailwindcss, and install tailwindcss/forms package.

I just found one tailwind component that are using

```
<input/>
```

for that functionality.

Here's the link for that : https://www.hyperui.dev/components/marketing/forms